# Using package files from script

Tags: python, package, distutils

If I have a script in my Python package, how can I get it to read other files from the package, since `__file__` contains (for example) `/usr/bin/myscript` and not `/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/mypackage/myscript`?

(The files are just templates, not modules.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [ResourceManager API](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/pkg_resources.html#resourcemanager-api) from `setuptools`' `pkg_resources`:

```
import pkg_resources
my_stream = pkg_resources.resource_stream(__name__, "foo.dat")
```

will open `my.package/my/package/foo.dat` as the file-like object `my_stream` for example.

This will work for regular as well as zipped eggs. Note however that this requires `setuptools` to be installed. For a solution that only uses the standard library (which is to be preferred), see @abarnert's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing based on a pathname will work, because your package, or your entire site-packages, could be, say, a zipfile, or the files may have been installed somewhere other than inside the package, etc.

The `pkgutil` module, in particular the [`get_data`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html) function, is the stdlib way to get the contents of a data file that's part of a package.

See [Installing Package Data](http://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data), and [Installing Additional Files](http://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files) for more info on making sure the files actually end up there in the first place.

If you want to use `setuptools` instead of just the stdlib, [`pkg_resources`](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/pkg_resources.html#resourcemanager-api) can make things easier/more flexible.

Comment: Hm… following Installing Additional Files puts things right in `/usr`. Is there a way to put it in a place more related to the package?

Comment: @minitech: Sure; those are relative paths, so you can just do `'share/myapp/foo'` instead of `'foo'`. Trying to do that in a platform-friendly way for every platform is not as much fun; use `setuptools` if you need anything complicated and cross-platform.

Comment: I do need something cross-platform; how would I use setuptools? It doesn’t appear to put the files anywhere.

Comment: @minitech: Did you read the docs? [Including Data Files](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#including-data-files) and the three following sections explain how it works. I'm still not sure whether you're trying to install package data files, or additional files/non-package data files, so I don't know how to tell you which one to read; just read both of them and maybe you'll know which is what you want. Finally, "It doesn't appear to put the files anywhere" isn't the kind of thing anyone can help you with; I have literally no idea what you tried, or what happened…

Comment: I read both docs and included a `package_data`. Where is it supposed to install the files?

Comment: (`package_data={"": "template/*"}`; `find / -name template 2> /dev/null` turns up nothing.)

Comment: Package data generally goes inside your package. Which means that if ou install the package as, say, an egg file, the files do not exist as files on your filesystem; they're inside the egg file. This is what the entire section [Accessing Data Files at Runtime](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#including-data-files) is about. And that's exactly why it says "It is strongly recommended that, if you are using data files, you should use the Resource Management API of pkg_resources to access them."